# OpenLDAP slapadd on a translucent overlay

Tags: openldap, overlay

I have an OpenLDAP database which seems to have one or two corrupt records (probably from machine crashes while update in process). Anyway, whenever anyone or anything access these records slapd crashes with a segmentation fault. I've narrowed it down to like I say just a couple or three records so I want to remove them.

It is a Berkley Database in the background so I tried the db_recover command which ran but did not do anything as I suspect it is just trying to replay transaction files...

so then I thought I would just dump the datbase with slapcat, using -c to ignore the errors. This provided me with a file which did not contain the corrupt entries. Then I was going to clear the DB and re-import this file with slapadd. The problem I had was that it complained about missing objectClass entries for some records. I tried the various switches to ignore schema checking but to no avail. This openldap is running as a translucent overlay to another ldap instance which contains those entries for each record. My file then only contains dn: uid: and repoName: (the latter being the overlay entry).

Has anyone got any thoughts on how I can read the ldif file back into a clean database without it complaining about the missing entries?

Thanks
P

Comment: Instead of rebuilding the whole database, did you try to just `ldapdelete` the involved entries ?

Comment: Hi Eric, Anything I try that access the record in question caused the ldap to crash? If I run slapschema I see this

5d120109 <= entry_decode: slap_str2undef_ad(eopleq): AttributeDescription contains inappropriate characters
# no data for entry id=0000002c

Comment: Ok in this case the slapcat/slapadd method you tried sounds like the only solution to me. What are the missing objectClass slapadd is complaining about ? You can also post some sample entries from the ldif file so we can see what it looks like.

Comment: Hey Eric - sorrry for delay in responding. I've since left the company where I was working with this so for me at least it has ceased to be a problem :). I just wanted to say thanks for devoting some time to helping me with it.